# Auto-detection of duplicates in import. To avoid multiple imports

Tags: import, externalid, duplicate-management, unique-field

Say I have three Unique(External ID) Fields (Email, Phone, Mobile)
But in my file, I do not have values for all three fields for all the rows. But I have atleast value for any one of the field.
In this scenario, I need to update the existing records from the file.
To achieve this, I need to import for three times.
Is there any other better way to import my file without importing the same file for 'n' times?

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing the same values in SF as you are missing in your CSV file, then you can build up a compisite key, say Email-Phone-Mobile.

You'll have to define a calc in Excel that fills in say "null" if the field is blank and do the same in SF in a calc there.

Make sure the order you define the fields in the calc is the same and that they have exactly the same output.

Ie, Excel should show `test@example.com-null-6506968744` and so should Salesforce.

Then you have a match field that you can use as an external Id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Say I have below set of records in Salesforce
1.   Name - Jai, Email- test@example.com, Phone - null                   
2.   Name - Casp, Email - null, Phone - 123 .
In my file,
1. Name - Jai Ganesh, Email - test@example.com, Phone-456
2. Name - Casp, Email - test1@example.com, Phone-123 .
Now to overwrite these data, I need to import it first matching by email and then import the same file again by matching phone,